# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Election Program

Tags: java

I have a short block of code that's throwing me an exception whenever I run it, and I can't understand why:

```
public class Debug 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[] electionName = {"John Smith", "Mary Miller", "Michael Duffy", "Tim Robison", "Joe Ashtony"};
        int[] electionVotes = {5000, 4000, 6000, 2500, 1800};
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < electionVotes.length; i++);
        {
           System.out.println(electionName[i] + electionVotes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone assist me?

Comment: Because you have a `;` after the for()

Comment: Note that declaring the loop variable `i` inside the `for` would make the problem obvious at the compilation stage, since `i` would not be accessible outside of the loop body: `for (int i = 0; ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop has a small error. it is terminated by a ;

for (i = 0; i < electionVotes.length; i++);

So the for loop effectively does nothing and just increments i to 5 after which you access the elements at index 5 in the 2 arrays which would throw the exception that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the end of your `for` statement. The problem comes from the character `;`

```
for (i = 0; i < electionVotes.length; i++); // <-
```

This is equivalent to :

```
for (i = 0; i < electionVotes.length; i++) {}

//Now, i = 5
{
  System.out.println(electionName[i] + electionVotes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lose the ; at the end of your 'for' loop!